# Android Universal Image Loader change HxW url parameters

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

When I pass in my Image URI to imageLoader.displayImage, it is automatically getting appended with _[W]x[H] at the end of each url.  Is there a way to override that string, or prevent it from getting appended at all?

The API i am calling already has querystring parameters setup for height and width.  It would be great if I could override this value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appendix is used only for memory cache. So different sizes of the same image can be cached in memory. This appendix isn't used for HTTP requests.

Comment: ok, thank you, I must have mis-interpreted the log output.  It looked to me that it was trying to send that url to my backend that is serving the images.  I will do some further testing. Thank you